# How to design button with box shadow in native script

Tags: html, xml, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am new in native script.I want to design button with box shadow

```css
.boxShadow {
   box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;
}
```

```html
<Button class="boxShadow" text="submit"></Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

Support for `box-shadow` is still an open [feature request](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/550). The workaround is to use [nativescript-cardview](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-cardview) plugin.

**Update:** The css attribute is now supported in NS8+

Comment: No longer a feature request. It is now implemented in NS8.

Answer (score 2):

i got plugin called "nativescript-ng-shadow" its works for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use for Android

```
.tvElevation{
    android-elevation:5;
}
```

see documentation [enter link description here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#nativescript-specific-css-properties-Using)

Answer (score 0):

Box-shadow is now supported in nativescript 8:

```
.boxShadow {
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}

.anotherBoxShadow {
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000000;
}

<Button class="boxShadow" text="submit"></Button>
```

More details here: [ns8 announcement](https://blog.nativescript.org/nativescript-8-announcement/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your style with Js by following code

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#boxShadow');
btn.style.boxShadow = '10px 10px 5px grey';
```

```html
<Button id="boxShadow" text="submit">btn</Button>
```

Comment: It does not work, because Nativescript does not have Document